# Frida not hooking Android method, implmentation unchanged

Tags: android, frida

I'm trying to hook a method in an app for which I don't know the source code but I have the APK.

I loaded the APK inside Android Studio and found that in the `classes2.dex` file there is a method named `posteitaliane.posteapp.appposteid.home.HomeAct.onBackPressed()` which triggers a dialog box saying "Are you sure you want to quit the app" or along the lines of that.

Here's the screenshot of the method being shown in Android Studio:

[image: onBackPressed Method]

I wrote this simple script just to test that simply prints to the console when the method is called:

```js
Java.perform(function() {
    var homeActClass = Java.use("posteitaliane.posteapp.appposteid.home.HomeAct");
    homeActClass.onBackPressed.implementation = function(){
        console.log("[ + ] onBackPressed called! ");
        this.onBackPressed(); //Call the original function
    }
});
```

Here is the Python script that loads the script and starts Frida:

```py
import frida, sys

with open("script_hook.js") as f:
        jscode = f.read()
process = frida.get_usb_device().attach('PosteID')
script = process.create_script(jscode)
print('[ * ] Attaching to PosteID application...')
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

When I'm on the home screen, and I'm sure that the class is right because the Android Studio profiler tells me this:
[image: Android Studio profiler showing home.HomeAct running]

If I try to go back the dialog box shows up, but nothing gets printed to the console.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: My recommendation to better understand what is going wrong is: first better use Frida binary from frida-tools Python package instead of a Python script. The command-line frida version has the advantage of automatic reloading when script is changed and the interactive shell. Second I would add a `console.log` at the end of the Java.Perform block. Frida had some bugs in latest versions where the Java block isn't executed at all unders certain conditions. In such a case it can help to save the script again which causes a reload and usually the full execution of the script.

Comment: I tried right now using the command ```frida -U PosteID -l script_hook.js``` and I tried to put a console log after the implementation function. The log works so the script gets executed, but still won't hook the function.

Comment: Is the `HomeAct` an activity that is directly declared in AndoridManifest.xml (class is not extended)? Alternatively you can hook all `onBackPressed` methods using frida-trace: `frida-trace -U PosteID -j '*!onBackPressed'`

Comment: Yes, there is an cativity with the right name in the AndroidManifest.xml: ```android:name="posteitaliane.posteapp.appposteid.home.HomeAct"```. If I try to do frida-trace it does log when I press back, but it still won't hook the method with the normal ```frida``` command.

Comment: Ok this is weird. I tried to use ```frida-trace``` to trace the back pressed on the home activity and now it doesn't work anymore. It hooks for every other screen except for the home. Also, sometimes it says that it's instrumenting 17 functions, sometimes 13, seemingly at random. I can't make any sense of this, it's not like the code changes at runtime.

Comment: This could be cause by ART optimization (try in frida script `Java.deoptimizeEverything()`) or if not all dex files are already loaded..

Comment: I tried but it doesn't make a difference. I tried creating a new virtual device from scratch and rerunning frida-server. The first time I ran ```frida-trace``` it instrumented 9 methods and logged the button press, the second it instrumented 14 methods and didn't. I just hit control-C and reran the command.